# How can translate the static property in Yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want  to translate static property using `Yii::t('app,'')`.

Here is my static variable:

```
public static $status = [
    '1' => 'Active',
    '0' => 'In Active',
];
```

If I use the translation here like this:

```
public static $status = [
    '1' => Yii::t('app','Active'),
    '0' => 'In Active',
];
```

It throw me error "Constant expression contains invalid operations".

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Bai jan aaj kal koi left nie hai.Please dakh le is ko.Aik tu YII2 ki community b slow hai

Comment: :) no , its not like that brother, agar kisi aur ne reply na kiya ho to zaroor kerta hu , you have an answer posted below that should work

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam got it bro thats nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't translate default values for object properties. The easiest way to solve it is to use static method:

```
public function getStatuses(): array {
    return [
        '1' => Yii::t('app', 'Active'),
        '0' => Yii::t('app', 'Inactive'),
    ];
}
```

Comment: thanx for the answer.how can i get the single statys by key,like this in index file    [
                'attribute' => 'is_active',
                'value'     => function ($model) {
                    return Lookup::getStatuse($model->is_active);
                },

                'filter'             => Lookup::getStatuses(),
                'filterInputOptions' => ['prompt' => Yii::t('app', 'Select Status'),
                                         'class'  => 'form-control'],
            ],

Comment: `Lookup::getStatuses()[$model->is_active]`

Answer (score 0):

you can also assign value to $status variable on class cunstractor or init method.